# Red5 Simple Recorder

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, red5

Im using Red5 simple recorder to capture videos and got following questions:
How can i stop it from generating meta file for each record im using jwplayer with playlist to stream it back and meta files appear in my playlist as well.
How can i add limitation to record to lets say 5min. Simple recorder is written in AS2 and 
use Sorenson Spark for video and Nellymoser for 1 clip 5min 480x270 generate file 30mb :)
when i tried wowza in-build recorder which is AS3 and Advanced Video Codec with SPEEX same 480x270 video is around 2mb.
And how can i add save button for the user if not pressed delete recorded video from the server.
Thank you

Comment: why not asking/looking here? https://code.google.com/p/red5/issues/list